# ACCESS SQL - Sum column grouped by a criteria and show also empty results

Tags: sql, ms-access

For this question, let's say I have two tables: Transactions and Categories.

Transactions:

- Transaction_ID
- Category_ID_FK
- TransactionDate
- TransactionValue

Categories:

- Category_ID
- CategoryDescritpion

I am trying to write a query that will sum all the TransactionValues that took place in a month (December, for instance) grouped by Category_ID and display the results for all category even when there are no Transactions on the table for a specific Category.

```
SELECT Categories.Category_ID, Sum(TransactionValue) 
FROM Categories LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Categories.Category_ID = Transactions.Category_ID_FK
WHERE Month(TransactionDate) = '12'
```

With this, I only get results from categories that have at least one transaction on the Transactions table.

Thank you all!

Comment: Your query has no `GROUP BY`, so you should be getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery in MS Access:

```
SELECT c.Category_ID, Sum(t.TransactionValue) 
FROM Categories as c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.*
      FROM Transactions as t
      WHERE Month(t.TransactionDate) = 12
     ) as t
     ON c.Category_ID = t.Category_ID_FK
GROUP BY c.Category_ID;
```

The typical SQL syntax would include the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.Category_ID, Sum(t.TransactionValue) 
FROM Categories as c LEFT JOIN
     Transactions as t
     ON c.Category_ID = t.Category_ID_FK AND Month(t.TransactionDate) = 12
GROUP BY c.Category_ID;
```

I don't think that MS Access supports this syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. That solved it.
The second solution didn't work on Access, as you mentioned. I got a "JOIN expression not supported" error